# Swift popViewController Send Data

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
class SelectTag: UIViewController {
    var selectedTag = [0,1,2]

    @IBAction func endSelectTag(_ sender: Any) {

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

can i add Data before run popViewController?

i tried this

```
(self.parent as! MyPage).seleteTag = seletedTag

Could not cast value of type UINavigationController to MyPage
```

Comment: Use delegate methods.

Comment: better use delegate or u can use Observer method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to pass data from `SelectTag` to `MyPage`.

One way to do this is to use the delegate pattern.

Create a `SelectTagDelegate`:

```
protocol SelectTagDelegate : class {
    func didSelectTag(tags: [Int])
}
```

Add this property in `SelectTag`:

```
weak var delegate: SelectTagDelegate?
```

And then change `endSelectTag` to:

```
@IBAction func endSelectTag(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didSelectTag(tags: selectedTag)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Make `MyPage` conform to `SelectTagDelegate` by implementing `didSelectTag`:

```
extension MyPage: SelectTagDelegate {
    func didSelectTag(tags: [Int]) {
        seleteTag = tags
    }
}
```

Now, when you are presenting `SelectTag`, set `self` as the delegate.

```
let selectTag = // get VC from storyboard or use segue.destination depending on your situation
selectTag.delegate = self
// present the VC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol SelectTagDelegate : Nsobject {
func clickedTag(tag: Int)
}

class SelectTag: UIViewController {
var selectedTag = [0,1,2]
var delegate : SelectTagDelegate?
@IBAction func endSelectTag(_ sender: Any) {
     self.delegate.clickedtag(selectedtag)

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```

Now when you create SelectTag object assign its delegate to self and implement the method  clickedTag .